# How to "re-run" query based on date range join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have this query that I would like to run with different dates for all customers.

```
select
    hey.*
    , case
        when (birthdate <= (CURRENT_DATE - 366)) then 365
        else extract(days
    from
        (hey.time1))
    end as days
from
    (
    select
        a.salesforce_id
        , max(a.birthdate) as birthdate
        , max(c2.completed) as max_date
        , min(c2.completed) as min_date
        , count(c2.id) as file_count
    from
        accounts a
    left join customers c 
on
        a.customer_id = c.id
    left join files c2 
on
        c.id = c2.createdbycustomerid
    where
        1 = 1
        and c2.completed is not null
        and c2.completed > (CURRENT_DATE - 366)
    group by
        a.salesforce_id
) as hey
```

My goal is to replace "CURRENT_DATE" with dates from another table. The table is a sequence of dates like `2020-09-01, 2020-10-01`

I've been googling a lot but can't get my head around it.

Comment: Update your post with debugging details, including sample input tables and expected output.

Comment: `completed in (select date from ...)`

Comment: Btw don't use left join and then filter on the inner table. And the null test is redundant.

Comment: try this query example to generate the sequences : SELECT array_agg(c.id),date_range FROM generate_series(current_date, current_date +interval '1 year' , interval '1 month') AS date_range
JOIN customers c ON c.completed >= date_range AND c.completed <= date_range+interval '1 month'
GROUP BY date_range